# Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : line 17 did not have 5 elements

Tags: r

I am using R to analyse my data set which is completely ok, there is no missing values. But still I am getting the error message below

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
```

line 17 did not have 5 elements
My file is in csv format (comma delimited).
Please help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: What command did you run to get this error? Look on line 17 for special characters (hash marks, apostrophes, quote marks etc)

Comment: the message "says something is wrong in line17 of your .csv". Have you tried to fix line 17 of you .csv file? For instance open it with a text editor and see what's wrong there

Comment: Well, I have checked thoroughly my data set and there is no such thing that you mentioned. Everything is fine., still getting that message. I used read.csv("file.csv", header=T, sep=",")